# Find $e^{z} = 1+ \sqrt{3} i$ for the exponential function in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function

I am working through a book on complex analysis. Now they give an example when introducing the exponential function.

We write $$e^{z} = e^{x} e^{iy},$$
where $x$ is the real part and $y$ the imaginary part of $z$.

Now I need to find the numbers $x+iy$ such that
$$ e^{z} = 1 + \sqrt{3}i,$$
and they start by rewriting this into
$$e^{x}e^{iy} = 2 e^{i \pi /3}.$$

Now I get the left part of the rewriting but how do they arrrive at $1+\sqrt{3}i= 2e^{i \pi /3}$  ?

I get the rest of the example, hence there is no need for finding the actual $x+iy$ for which the equation holds.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$e^{i\frac {\pi} 3}=\cos (\frac {\pi} 3)+i\sin \frac {\pi} 3= \frac 1  2+i\frac {\sqrt 3} 2$

Answer (score 1):

I believe you've seen Euler's equation somewhere in that book.

Long story short, it says that all outputs of $f(x)=e^{ix}$ lie on the unit circle in the complex plane.

Calculating the polar co-ordinates for $1+\sqrt{3}$ gives $(2, \dfrac{\pi}{3}^c)$

And scaling it down by 2 places it on the unit circle. Hence by Euler's equation it is an output from that very angle i.e. $e^{i\dfrac{\pi}{3}}$, twice that is the original number which is $2e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}}$

But to be complete I think $z=\ln{2}+\dfrac{\pi}{3}i$

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration. To be entirely complete $z = \ln{2} + (\frac{1}{3}+2n)\pi i$ with $n \in \mathbb{N}.$

Comment: Interesting. Thank you.